# Nested results in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use ElasticSearch within the Java API. As a JSON File (named Google.json) I am using the following structure:

```
{
 "markers": [
 {
          "point":"new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479)", 
      "homeTeam":"Lawrence Library",
          "awayTeam":"LUGip",
          "markerImage":"images/red.png",
          "information": "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of",
          "fixture":"Wednesday 7pm",
          "capacity":"",
         },
         {
          "point":"new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.75022)", 
      "homeTeam":"Hamilton Library",
          "awayTeam":"LUGip HW SIG",
          "markerImage":"images/white.png",
          "information": "Linux users group meets second Tuesday.",
          "fixture":"Tuesday 7pm",
          "capacity":"",
         }
       ]
}
```

Using Jackson I am converting this file into a Java Hashmap. Then I try to search in field "fixture" for the Word "Tuesday". I am finding this, but as a result I am getting the complete "markers" List back instead of only the second element. I am now wondering what the problem is with my approach.

Here is my Java code:

```
JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
String path="d:\\Google.json";

Node node = nodeBuilder().local(true).node();
Client client = node.client();

/* Jackson mapper*/     
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File jsonFile=new File(path);

try {
        /*Read in file using Jackson into HashMap*/
        Map<String, Object> mapObject=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapObject = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});

        /*Create index*/            
        IndexResponse response=null;
        response = client.prepareIndex(index, type)
                .setSource(mapObject)               
                .execute()
                .actionGet();


        } catch (JsonParseException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

    QueryBuilder qb=QueryBuilders.matchQuery("fixture","Tuesday");

    SearchResponse response= client.prepareSearch(index)
            .setTypes(type)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(qb)
            .setFrom(0)
            .setSize(100)
            .setExplain(true)
            .execute().actionGet();

    SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();

    System.out.println("Current results: " + results.length);

    for (SearchHit hit : results) {
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        Map<String,Object> result = hit.getSource();   
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

It would be great to get any hint/help on this!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Jackson put everything into one JSON object. This was then indexed as a single document in elasticsearch.

When running a query, Elasticsearch always returns full documents as the result. A partial document cannot be returned. Therefore, when running your query, all documents that contains an element with a fixture named "Tuesday" gets returned. Since your single document contains both Wednesday and Tuesday as fixtures, both these elements gets returned even though you only searched for Tuesday. The whole document got returned even though only the part of it that matches "Tuesday" actually matched the query.

The following chapter is a must read: [Modelling your data](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/modeling-your-data.html)  Basically, there are two ways around this:

1) Index your teams as separate documents. This you can do by looping through the array of teams and indexing each one under the same type (eg team_type). Now when running a search query you will only get the team document that matches the query.

2) Index the teams as a nested documents inside the parent. You can then use the inner_hits functionality to return the nested document that matched your query as an element in an inner_hit array. This functionality is very new and only available in the newly released Elasticsearch 1.5. See here: [inner_hits](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)

Edit:

Create a new index with mapping like follows (change "index" and "type" to something else):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index/_mapping/type' -d '
{
    "mapping": {
        "properties": {
            "point": {
                "type": "String",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "homeTeam": {
                "type": "String",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
                "type": "String",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index'
```

Now change the code to something like this:

```
File jsonFile=new File("testmsg.txt");                      
try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(jsonFile)) {                           
    //read configuration from a JSON file
    JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(is);
    if(node.get("markers").isArray()) {
        ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode)node.get("markers");
        arrayNode.elements().forEachRemaining(jnode -> {
            if(jnode.isObject()) {
                ObjectNode obj = (ObjectNode)jnode;

                IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(index, type)
                      .setSource(obj.toString()).execute().actionGet();
            }
        });
    }
}                
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You are now indexing each element of the array as a separate document. Searching for a specific one will now only yield that specific document.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have trying to do the first solution but I did not manage it / find some information at other related questions. Could you please give me a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Ok Ive updated with an example, let me know if I understood correctly

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.